# How to format MDX in the Visual Studio Data Tools

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssas, mdx

Is there a way to format an MDX query in the Visual Studio Data Tools. I'm referring to the Cube browser which lets you auto-generate and create your own MDX queries against a cube.

Right now I'm using http://mdx.mosha.com/default.aspx to format queries!

Comment: mdx.mosha.com... using it since 4 years now

Comment: :( srsly? VSDT hasn't built that tooling?

Comment: update: mdx.mosha.com is now offline.

Comment: Some tools you can find in this review http://byobi.com/blog/2013/03/top-free-tools-for-ssas-2012-developers/

Comment: The only website that I've found that is still working is [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm), There also used to be a Excel plugin that did this, [OlapPivotTableExtension](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c2927c8-0e4a-4658-a3d4-55691a613471/how-to-view-mdx-query-in-excel-sheet?forum=sqlanalysisservices) I think that's gone now though... It leveraged another page that I think is gone too. Really I don't think there are any options, as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of [Mosha's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosha_Pasumansky) valuable content on MDX are nowadays getting difficult to find.

But, his MDX Studio is still available here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio/

This also has a 'Format' option (in addition to many useful things)

[image]